# How do I replace row values with images?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, visualization

I am doing a data viz related to NBA. Here is how it looks until now:
[image]

I want to show the teams with their logo images instead of the plain team name texts. What can we do?

Data Source: https://data.world/makeovermonday/2019w17

Comment: Do you have a way to add any HTML or an image source? If yes, then it would be as simple as passing in a file name of the image logo to a URL/location. You could write a case statement by switching the image file.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't collected the images yet.